# Forbidden Accses in request data extraction

Tags: python, python-requests, data-science

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


cookies = {
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.236843734.1691605817',
    '_fbp': 'fb.1.1691605881206.167693788',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'kjuzvp31al0rmp5kjjc1qzo1',
    'nativelogin': 'lastontime=168EA78B-5039-4EEE-8620-DE93933D9836',
    'nativeloginmaster': 'lastontime=168EA78B-5039-4EEE-8620-DE93933D9836',
    'nativetemp': 'Lang=TR',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'b2b.kamilturk.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'tr,tr-TR;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6',
    # 'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.236843734.1691605817; _fbp=fb.1.1691605881206.167693788; ASP.NET_SessionId=kjuzvp31al0rmp5kjjc1qzo1; nativelogin=lastontime=168EA78B-5039-4EEE-8620-DE93933D9836; nativeloginmaster=lastontime=168EA78B-5039-4EEE-8620-DE93933D9836; nativetemp=Lang=TR',
    'referer': 'https://b2b.kamilturk.com/Login/Login',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


data = {
    'adi': '******',
    'Sifre': '******',
    'SmsSifre': '',
}

response = requests.post('https://b2b.kamilturk.com/Giris/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    # Yanıtın içeriğini alıp yazdırabilirsiniz
    print(response.content.decode('utf-8'))  # Yanıtın içeriğini UTF-8 kodlamasına göre çözümle

else:
    print(f"Hata kodu: {response.status_code}")

with requests.session() as s:
    login_url = 'https://b2b.kamilturk.com/Login/Login'
    r = s.get(login_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    
    s.post(login_url,data=data, headers=headers,cookies=cookies)    
    print(r.text)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYR5L.png)

mean forbidden acces

and

```
print(response.content.decode('utf-8')) = {"success":true,"responseText":"Success","returnurl":"/","token":"168EA78B-5039-4EEE-8620-DE93933D9836","KullaniciAdiDogruMu":false}
```

I think problem

```
"KullaniciAdiDogruMu":false english mean : usernameiscorrect: false
```

Comment: Help us to help you - What exactly is your question?  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks